# Deference C# List<T> pointer externally

Tags: c#, c++, list, pointers, reverse-engineering

I am working in a project in which I reverse engineer a C# application that has a List. I have managed to get the raw pointer to that list externally and I'd like to iterate through it's contents in C++. I do not know how C#'s List is implemented, I've read it works in a similar way as the C++'s std::vector. How would I go about accessing the List's contents? Upon deferencing the List pointer I saw a two values that look like pointers and one that appears to be the List's length, but deferencing those pointers I couldn't get to anything the resembles the element type...
I doubt they are implemented identically, but I wonder if casting the pointer to an std::vector would work. I have the type's size which I supposed would be required to go through the elements.

Comment: Don't worry about how `List` works. That's inconsequential. What matters is how it behaves. In fact, you don't care how the C# program works. All that matters is how it behaves. Code describes behaviour and you want to reimplement the C# program's behaviour, not the code, in C++, following C++'s Idioms and best practices. Cling to tightly to C#'s idioms and best practices and your translation will be a gibbering wreck.

Comment: A List reference is a managed reference. Unless it's pinned, it may up and move while you are looking at it (since garbage collection may move live objects, and that happens on another thread). The only real way to iterate through a list to call GetEnumerator and then use the enumerator you get to walk the list. But, that enumerator is also managed so it may up and move too

Comment: Also worth noting is that a `List<T>` supports any `T`, whether T is a value-type (i.e.  a `struct` like an `int` or a `DateTime`) or a reference type (i.e., a `class`). In a list of value types, the width of the type is significant, if you are working with reference types, the list contains references (to objects that may move)

Comment: On the C++ side the only thing you can safely cast to a `vector<T>` is a `vector<T>`. See the [Strict Aliasing Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

Comment: I suggest you create a little C# application that creates some lists with known values in memory and then inspect the memory to see how you're able to locate those values. Since this is a garbage collected environment, I imagine it might be more complicated than just following a few pointers. There might be a custom lookup table or some magic math you have to do to find the right memory address.

Comment: This is all fairly misguided. In short dont do it. Project the List to an array, and Marshall it like you would any other array (so the pointer is taken care of, the length is accurate, and the array is pinned).

Comment: I do not have access to the original code, I tried what @MikeFisher suggested and I managed to find the list's elements sequentially in memory and confirmed they were being accessed with a debugger, I couldn't relate the address I was at to the original list address though. Since C# is much higher level than C++, I'm pretty sure I cannot cast the pointer to a list, and even if I could, I'm sure the garbage colletion would mess me up anyways... Is there any way to achieve this externally at all?